# How to display two months data in a single line graph in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, charts

I want to display data from 2 months in a line graph in google sheet. I tried and only one months data is displayed. Please help. Following is just a demo

| date | birth | death |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30/6/2021 | 22 | 6 |
| 1/7/2021 | 5 | 43 |
| 2/7/2021 | 9 | 22 |
| 3/7/2021 | 12 | 21 |
| 4/7/2021 | 23 | 11 |

Comment: Your chart should only display line for dead and birth only with date as X-axis. If you want to display dead and birth for different month, then you should use bar chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should display your data as bar chart if you want the result in grouping by month (add new column for month value only), to display the trend for dead and birth over the year, then you should choose line chart, here is how the two charts look like:

[image]